# Silent release on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a possibility to release an app on Google Play without it being 'officialy released', advertised etc.?

Let me explain. I would like to release my application to some (quite large) audience in order to build a database. To these users I would like it to be available without the need to join any beta testers group. In the same time, to average user the app is not going to be very useable. So, at first I would like to narrow average users installing my app as much as possible. It would be great if I could postpone Google Play featuring it on any lists.

I hope I made myself clear. Any ideas?

Comment: I think what you want is called staged rollout

Comment: I would still recommend using a Google Group and beta testing it through the Google Play Store so only the users you invite can see it through the store.  This provides one of the easiest update capabilities as well for all those small fixes that will come along the way.

Comment: @JaySnayder It seems that this is the only way. But I'm worried that this is a bit tedious for non-technical folk. What I want exactly is open beta, without the need to join any groups. But it does not seem possible.

Comment: You can do an open beta by asking people to send you an email, for example. Then you add them to the group. OR, you release your app with the words "(PUBLIC) BETA" in the name and description, and once done your just remove them. It can also be a way forward but you are taking the risk to receive public negative comments from people who didn't get this is a beta (or what a beta is).

Comment: @Shlublu, thanks. It is a great idea (so simple) with 'beta' in the app name.

Comment: @user146386 Thanks! I added that to my answer to make it complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can release your app as a Beta release. It will be limited to a certain audience that you define in Google Play (there is a Users administration feature dedicated to that). This sounds like a normal process for what you are willing to achieve.

Before that, you can also release your app as an Alpha. The principle is the same but the group is different. Alpha is perfect to get rid of most of the bugs your application may have.

So, to summarize, the process is:

1- You build your app, and test it on your own 
2- Then you release it as an Alpha to a very small group 
3- Reiterate 1- and 2- as long as you have bugs reported by the Alpha testers 
4- You promote your app as a Beta to another group, usually larger. Data is created and more bugs, less obvious, are reported 
5- Reiterate fixing and 4- as long as you have bugs reported by the Beta testers 
 
6- You promote your app as a Production release. Now everybody can use it.

You may also, once all this done, release your app with the words "(PUBLIC) BETA" in its name and description. Once the public beta testing done you'll just have to remove these words to let the users know this is no longer a Beta but a Stable version. 
Caveat: by doing this way, you'll have to expect your app to receive negative comments and rating from users who didn't get this is a beta, or what a beta is.